# How can I use Selenium to wait for an element to be visible on a page (but then move on to something else)?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriverwait

I'm trying to scrape URLs off of a web page, and they're located inside of a rankings table which takes a few seconds to load.

What I want to do is wait until the rankings table finishes loading, then grab it by its id and iterate over the elements.

This is the code I'm using to grab the page and wait:

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(cred_path)
    driver.get(page)

    wait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'sc-ljMRFG hgfcNB rankings-table')))
    #soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, features='lxml')
    #print(soup.prettify())
    rankings = soup.find_all('div', {'class': "sc-ljMRFG hgfcNB rankings-table"})[0] 

    print(rankings)
```

As far as I can tell the code is actually working up to that point (I can visually see the table loading when the window opens), but then it throws a timeout error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ethereum_scraper_dappRadarv2.py", line 377, in <module>
    general_dapp_page()
  File "ethereum_scraper_dappRadarv2.py", line 39, in general_dapp_page
    _ = wait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'sc-ljMRFG hgfcNB rankings-table')))
  File "/Users/trentfowler/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
0   chromedriver                        0x0000000104dd4269 __gxx_personality_v0 + 582729
1   chromedriver                        0x0000000104d5fc33 __gxx_personality_v0 + 106003
2   chromedriver                        0x000000010491ce28 chromedriver + 171560
3   chromedriver                        0x00000001049523d2 chromedriver + 390098
4   chromedriver                        0x0000000104952591 chromedriver + 390545
5   chromedriver                        0x00000001049846b4 chromedriver + 595636
6   chromedriver                        0x000000010496f9fd chromedriver + 510461
7   chromedriver                        0x0000000104982462 chromedriver + 586850
8   chromedriver                        0x000000010496fc23 chromedriver + 511011
9   chromedriver                        0x000000010494575e chromedriver + 337758
10  chromedriver                        0x0000000104946a95 chromedriver + 342677
11  chromedriver                        0x0000000104d908ab __gxx_personality_v0 + 305803
12  chromedriver                        0x0000000104da7863 __gxx_personality_v0 + 399939
13  chromedriver                        0x0000000104dacc7f __gxx_personality_v0 + 421471
14  chromedriver                        0x0000000104da8bba __gxx_personality_v0 + 404890
15  chromedriver                        0x0000000104d84e51 __gxx_personality_v0 + 258097
16  chromedriver                        0x0000000104dc4158 __gxx_personality_v0 + 516920
17  chromedriver                        0x0000000104dc42e1 __gxx_personality_v0 + 517313
18  chromedriver                        0x0000000104ddb6f8 __gxx_personality_v0 + 612568
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff205d18fc _pthread_start + 224
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff205cd443 thread_start + 15
```

(Note that the subsequent `rankings =` and `print` statements are not executed, so far as I can tell)

My current interpretation is that selenium is executing the wait command just fine but then times out because there's no further instructions given directly to it (i.e. I'm not invoking `click()` on anything).

I've RTFM, but the selenium documentation is awfully sparse. Is there really no concept of waiting until an element loads then moving on to some other processing task? Do I *have* to interact with the element in some way, and if so, what would be the best kind of interaction given that all I really want is to iterate over the internal elements?

Comment: Could you include the full error message?

Comment: @AlarmClockMan added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you are using a wrong locator as **`sc-ljMRFG hgfcNB rankings-table`** can't be the value of the **`ID`** attribute but possibly the value of `class` attribute.

So effectively you need to change:

```
wait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'sc-ljMRFG hgfcNB rankings-table')))
```

to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CLASS_NAME*:

  ```
  wait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'rankings-table')))
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  wait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.sc-ljMRFG.hgfcNB.rankings-table')))
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm afraid that didn't work.

I was using `id` inappropriately, but even using `By.CLASS_NAME` causes the same behavior. It opens the page, sits there for 5 seconds, then throws an error.

Comment: @TrentFowler Do you se the same error as before?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong. That does appear to have resolved the issue. Thanks!